# jaxb - deserializing list of pojo with unbounded list inside

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I hava a xml response like below:

```
<out>
<documentsInfoByClaimNumber>

               <caseId>654321</caseId>

               <documentDetails>

                  <documentId>123456</documentId>

                  <documentSource>brahbrah</documentSource>

                  <category>brahbrah</category>

                  <documentType>brahbrah</documentType>

                  <documentName>brahbrah.brah</documentName>

                  <createdDate>2020-06-22T17:00:25</createdDate>

               </documentDetails>

</documentsInfoByClaimNumber>
</out>
```

**both documentsInfoByClaimNumber and documentDetails are unbounded list, could appear once or more**

below are my pojos, I'm using lombok:
jackson XmlMapper for parsing, with jaxb annotations

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement(name = "getDocumentInfoByClaimNumberResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GetDocumentInfoByClaimNumberRes {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "out")
    @XmlElement(name = "documentsInfoByClaimNumber")
    private List<Wrapper> out;

    @Data
    public static class Wrapper{
        private int caseId;

//        private DocumentDetails documentDetails;  without list it works
        @XmlElement(name="documentDetails")
        private List<DocumentDetails> documentDetails;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class DocumentDetails {
    private String documentId;
    private String documentSource;
    private String category;
    private String documentType;
    private String documentName;
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
}
```

the problem is, with documentDetails only appear once, I got something like

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.service.casetrack.payload.DocumentDetails` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('123456')
(through reference chain: GetDocumentInfoByClaimNumberRes["out"]->java.util.ArrayList[1]->GetDocumentInfoByClaimNumberRes$Wrapper["documentDetails"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

I can deserialize it without using List, but thus I can't deal with two or more elements. Any tricks for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check below .. i wish that is help for you

```
package xml;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jakarta.xmlbind.JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class stackOverFlowTest {

    @Test
    public void test01() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        StringBuffer xml = new StringBuffer()
                .append("<out>")
                .append("   <documentsInfoByClaimNumber name=\"first\">")
                .append("      <caseId>654321</caseId>")
                .append("      <documentDetails>")
                .append("         <documentId>123456</documentId>")
                .append("         <documentSource>brahbrah</documentSource>")
                .append("         <category>brahbrah</category>")
                .append("         <documentType>brahbrah</documentType>")
                .append("         <documentName>brahbrah.brah</documentName>")
                .append("         <createdDate>2020-06-22T17:00:25</createdDate>")
                .append("      </documentDetails>")
                .append("   </documentsInfoByClaimNumber>")
                .append("   <documentsInfoByClaimNumber name=\"secode\">")
                .append("      <caseId>654321</caseId>")
                .append("      <documentDetails>")
                .append("         <documentId>123456</documentId>")
                .append("         <documentSource>brahbrah</documentSource>")
                .append("         <category>brahbrah</category>")
                .append("         <documentType>brahbrah</documentType>")
                .append("         <documentName>brahbrah.brah</documentName>")
                .append("         <createdDate>2020-06-22T17:00:25</createdDate>")
                .append("      </documentDetails>")
                .append("   </documentsInfoByClaimNumber>")
                .append("</out>");

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.builder().defaultUseWrapper(false)
                .addModule(new JakartaXmlBindAnnotationModule())
                .disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_USING_DEFAULT_VALUE)
                .addModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .build();

        GetDocumentInfoByClaimNumberRes result = xmlMapper.readValue(xml.toString(),
                GetDocumentInfoByClaimNumberRes.class);

        result.getDocumentsInfoByClaimNumber().forEach(f -> {
            log.info("name={} caseId={} list=>{}", f.getName(), f.getCaseId(), f.getDocumentDetails().toString());
        });
        // log.info("result=>{}", result.toString());

    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    @XmlRootElement(name = "out")
    static class GetDocumentInfoByClaimNumberRes {
        @XmlAttribute
        private String name;

        @XmlElement(name = "documentsInfoByClaimNumber")
        private List<DocumentsInfoByClaimNumber> documentsInfoByClaimNumber;
    }

    @Data
    @ToString
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class DocumentsInfoByClaimNumber {
        @XmlAttribute
        private String name;

        @XmlElement
        private String caseId;

        @XmlElement(name = "documentDetails")
        private List<DocumentDetails> documentDetails;
    }

    @Data
    @ToString
    @NoArgsConstructor
    static class DocumentDetails {
        private String documentId;
        private String documentSource;
        private String category;
        private String documentType;
        private String documentName;
        private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    }

}
```

result

```
11:03:20 INFO  [main] xml.stackOverFlowTest - name=first caseId=654321 list=>[stackOverFlowTest.DocumentDetails(documentId=123456, documentSource=brahbrah, category=brahbrah, documentType=brahbrah, documentName=brahbrah.brah, createdDate=2020-06-22T17:00:25)]
11:03:20 INFO  [main] xml.stackOverFlowTest - name=secode caseId=654321 list=>[stackOverFlowTest.DocumentDetails(documentId=123456, documentSource=brahbrah, category=brahbrah, documentType=brahbrah, documentName=brahbrah.brah, createdDate=2020-06-22T17:00:25)]
```

Comment: A good answer would include some explanation about why this solution fixes the OPs problem. Maybe take a look here: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: work as a charm with this module, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by switch to `jackson-xml` annotations instead of `jaxb` annotations with:

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
```

But I wonder how could it be handled in `jaxb`, `@XmlElement` seems not working